# Can you use "adequately" and "well"?

Tags: contradiction, pleonasms

I ran across this clause and I’m wondering if it’s okay to use "adequately" and "well" together. I think of "well" as being more than adequate, so does "adequate" contradict or seriously undermine the word "well"? Is "well" even needed?

> ... a morass of interconnected pieces did the job adequately well ...

Comment: So you're asking if both together adds anything to either alone, is that right?

Comment: Yes.  It means "well enough."

Comment: @Benjamin Harman that is included under a synonym for just "adequately" here https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/adequately

Answer (score 1):

I think the following sentence,

> ...a morass of interconnected pieces did the job adequately well...

should be changed to,

> ...a morass of interconnected pieces did the job adequately...

because **adequately** means to a satisfactory degree. There is no need to add **well** to the sentence after **adequately** because then the meaning of the sentence translates to something like **a good satisfactory degree** and that actually does not make any sense.

Answer (score -1):

I would have to say no.

"Well" correlates with good. It is an entirely positive term.

Adequate really means "good enough", (adequately = well enough) such that it is a qualified term. It is positive, sure, but it carries a qualifier that says it's not quite "good" or else I would have said "good". However, "adequate" or "good enough" is in no way negative either. It does not fall below expectations or requirements, it just does rise above them either.

I think what might be happening in the quote you provided is a response to connotation. I have encountered this problem lately with the word "satisfactory" too. For a long time, "satisfactory" and "adequate" have been used somewhat euphemistically to avoid saying anything bad but to distinguish from actually saying "good". As a result, many people, when they hear "adequate" or "satisfactory", think "not good".

Perhaps the original author of the quote in the question wanted to mitigate the light negative connotation that "adequate" has acquired by pairing it with "well". However, this is not really necessary and certainly would not be recommended usage.

Comment: I'd love a comment to go with the downvote so that I can better understand why this answer might be wrong.

Comment: I can not be sure, since I am not the voter, but sometimes you can write a perfectly accurate answer, and people will vote against it on proceedural or qualitative grounds. It is possible that somebody thinks the question should not have been answered in its present state (Edwin Ashworth does that quite often for example), or [perhaps somebody thinks you have not done enough to prove your assertions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You can not do much to fix the former, but you can try to fix the latter by adding references, quotations, usage graphs from ngrams, et cetera.